# Polymer: get the value of paper-input inside a paper-dialog after paper-button press "ok"

Tags: javascript, polymer

i need to get the value of some paper-input fields inside a paper-dialog after a press on a "ok" paper-button.

I have:

```
...
<paper-dialog id="notediag" heading="Add Note" transition="paper-dialog-transition-center">
    <paper-input id="dialog-add-note-header" label="Header"
        value="{{valHeader}}"></paper-input>
    <br>
    <paper-input id="dialog-add-note-text" label="Text"></paper-input>

    <paper-button label="Cancel" dismissive></paper-button>
    <paper-button label="Ok" affirmative default
        on-click="{{addNote}}"></paper-button>
</paper-dialog>
...

<script>
Polymer('note-list',{
  addNote: function(e, detail, sender)
  {
        var header=???
        console.log("add note "+header);
  }
});
</script>
```

I tried multiple ways to find the values of the paper-input fields but not found a propper way to do it. `e.target.templateInstance` does not work. A call to `document.querySelector('#dialog-add-note-header')` results in a null.

Any ideas?

Thanks for you help.

Stefan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`{{valHeader}}` creates a property inside your *note-list* elelemt which is bound to the input value of the *paper-input*.

You can access it with

```
var header = this.valHeader
```

`document.querySelector('#dialog-add-note-header')` doesn't work, because the *paper-input* element is inside the shadow DOM of the `paper-dialog`. But you can use Polymer's node finding utility `this.$.dialogAddNoteHeader` (rename your id attribute to contain no dashes) to access the input element directly.

Comment: Thanks Dirk! `this.$.dialogAddNoteHeader` works like a charm!