# Polymer: Not able to get input from paper-input element

Tags: javascript, input, polymer

I have just started exploring polymer.js. I want to get input from paper-input element. And want to read it. 
I have a paper button. On clicking that button, value in paper-input should be stored in global variable USER_NAME.

I referred the stackoverflow post [Polymer: get the value of paper-input inside a paper-dialog after paper-button press "ok"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24594947/polymer-get-the-value-of-paper-input-inside-a-paper-dialog-after-paper-button-p)

But it is not working for me.
Here is my code:

```
<div id="profileInfoForm">
 <h2>Tell us about you...</h2>
 <div class="profileField">
                    <h5>Name :</h5>
                    <paper-input name="profileName" id="profileNameId" inputValue="{{ valHeader }}" label="What will we call you ?"></paper-input>
                </div>

                <div class="profileField" style="text-align: center;">
                    <div onclick="fetchDataFromForm();" id="proceedButton" class="button raised blue" style="text-align: center">
                        <div class="center" fit>Proceed</div>
                        <paper-ripple fit></paper-ripple>
                    </div>
                </div>

</div>


<script>
 var USER_NAME="";
Polymer('note-list',{
    fetchDataFromForm: function(e, detail, sender)
      {
        USER_NAME = this.valHeader;

      }
    });
</script>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The example you copied from was not complete. The script at the bottom is defining an element called `note-list`, but they omitted the part where they began the element's definition. See [this jsbin](http://jsbin.com/nafireye/1/edit?html,output) for a working version of your code.

Two takeaways:

1. `Polymer('note-list', ...` is only useful if you also create a `polymer-element` definition.
2. To use Polymer's declarative event handling you must use the `on-[event]` syntax (notice the dash) and use handlebars `{{ }}` around the handler name in the attribute value.

Comment: I also took the `fit` attribute off of the "Proceed" `div` and added `position: relative` to its parent to make the `paper-ripple` work correctly.